# Step function converging to $f$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ a measurable function with $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X$. Show that there exists a sequence of step functions, $\{ \phi_n\}$, such that $\phi_n(x)\leq f(x)$ for all
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in X$, and $0\leq \phi_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$.

I know how to prove that there exists a sequence of $\textbf{simple}$ functions
with the above asked properties (this is given in the book I use):

> For each $n$ take $A_n^i=\{x\in X: (i-1)2^{-n}\leq f(x)<i2^{-n}\}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n2^n$. The
>   $A_n^i$ are disjoint w.r.t. $i$, and they are measurable as $f$ is a measurable function.
>   Now we define $\phi_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n2^n}2^{-n}(i-1)I_{A_n^i}(x)$, where $I_{A_n^i}(x)$
>   is the indicator function indicating whether $x$ is in $A_n^i$ or not. $\phi_n$ is a step function for each $n$. Also, $0\leq \phi_n(x)\leq \phi_{n+1}(x)\leq f(x)$ holds for all $x$ and $n$. If $x$ is fixed, $0\leq f(x)-\phi_{n}(x)\leq 2^{-n}$ holds for $n$ large enough. So $\phi_{n}\to f$ holds.

Now, because $(X,S,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists a sequence $\{X_n\}$ with
$\cup_{n=1}^\infty X_n=X$ and $\mu^*(X_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. I thought that maybe we could do the following: take $B_n^i = \{x\in \cup_{k=1}^n X_n:(i-1)2^{-n}\leq f(x)<i2^{-n}\}$. This way we apply the routine of the proof for simple functions to the $X_n$, and, as the $B_n^i$ are subsets of finite unions of $X_n$, $\mu^*(B_n^i)<\infty$.
Problem is, for each $n$ we can find $N>n$ with $\phi_n(x)=0$ for $x\in X_N$, and from this we could conclude that $\phi_n\not\to f$.

A little help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is (for you) the difference between a "simple function" and a "step function"?

Comment: A simple function is in the book I use defined as a function $\phi:X\to \mathbb{R}$ assuming only a finite number of values, so that we can write $\phi(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i I_{A_i}(x)$. A step function is defined as a simple function with $\mu^*(A_i)<\infty$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any sequence $(f_n)_n$ of simples functions with $0 \leq f_n \leq f$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise.

Take $A_n \subset X$ with $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$, $\bigcup_n A_n = X$ and $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Such sets exist by $\sigma$-finiteness.

Check that $\phi_n := f_n \cdot \chi_{A_n}$ (where $\chi_M$ is the indicator function of $M$) is indeed a step function with $0 \leq \phi_n \leq f$.

Now, let $x \in X$ arbitrary. Then $x \in A_n$ for some $n$ and thus $x \in A_m$ for all $m \geq n$. This yields (for $m \neq n$) that $$\phi_m (x) = f_m(x) \rightarrow f(x)$$ for $m \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Actually, is this really correct? Because, suppose, if we would choose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, then we could for all $n$ find some $x\not\in A_n$, so that $f(x)-\phi_n(x)=1-0=1$, which would mean that $\phi_n\not\to f$, right?

Comment: We just want pointwise convergence, i.e. you fix $x$ and $\varepsilon$ and then you have to find $n_0$ so that for all $n \geq n_0$ we have $|f(x)- f_n(x)| < \varepsilon$. What you seem to think about is uniform convergence. As you noted, the statement is false in that case.